# Cutting down blinds (Specifically metal frame - not the blind itself)

Tags: blinds, metal-cutting

I have some blinds that have metal side pieces made from (I believe) aluminum. The sides are runners that the blinds and the handle slide up and down in.

The problem is that these are about 5mm too long for the height of the window so I need to cut them down. I know nothing about DIY and have few tools :P

What tools do I need to do this? I assume some kind of hand saw might do? Or is there a power tool? I don't mind spending a little money on a tool that I can use in future for other projects. But specifically what do I need to cut through thin metal reasonable neatly.

Any advice welcome, I want to learn (Even if it's you should get someone in to do it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hand tool for cutting metal is called a hacksaw. For neater cuts, select a blade with fine (narrowly spaced) teeth.

There are many kinds of hacksaws available, but for this use you'd want a traditional one. There are mini hacksaws which might be cheaper but a larger one will make the work faster and the cuts smoother.

After you cut, you can smooth the edges using some sandpaper or a medium/fine sanding sponge. Be careful as you handle the piece because cut metal edges can be sharp.

Comment: Right... I know about hacksaws. Wasn't sure they would be suitable for cutting metal. They are cheap enough, I'll give it a try.

Thanks.

Comment: Got a suitable small hacksaw and tried this.
It wore the blade out pretty quickly but worked perfectly!
Thanks :) it's all easy when you know how